# UI5 OData - Filter automatic READ call after Create

Tags: odata, sapui5

Hi have developed an App with Planninng Calendar.

This is an example of my oData call when starting the App. Here I set some filters.

```
EmployeeSet?$skip=0&$top=1000&$filter=substringof(%2799999999%27,orgId)%20and%20startDate%20le%20datetime%272022-12-01T10%3a59%3a14%27%20and%20endDate%20ge%20datetime%272022-12-31T11%3a59%3a14%27&$expand=EmployeeToAppointment%2cEmployeeToSpecialDates
```

My poblem comes, after I add a new Appointment with method Create, the Calendar is refreshed  and the READ method is called, but there is no filter, so all the data is read, without filtering. **Is there any possibility to filter this automatic READ call?**

Below is an example of the automatic READ call

```
GET EmployeeSet('00002889')/EmployeeToAppointment?$skip=0&$top=1000
```

Comment: What is the target version of SAPUI5? What is the OData specification version (V2 or V4)? Could you share the call stack for the automatic READ call (Who initiates it)?

Comment: SAPUI5 is 1.60.30
OData is V2
The GET Method is called automatically after I call the method create of the Model: 
oModel.create(sPath, oAppointment,
Is my understanding, that the model refreshes automatically because I made some changes on it, and that's OK, the problem is that is reading without filtering(dates)
I would send you the stack too, but I don't how to get to exact point where the READ method is called

Comment: As you might know already, support for 1.60 ended last year. I'd strongly encourage to migrate to one of the newer [SAPUI5 releases that are still maintained](https://ui5.sap.com/versionoverview.html) to benefit from continuous security patches. Could you try if the $filter is still not applied if run with the latest SAPUI5 version? E.g. bootstrapping with `src="https://ui5.sap.com/1.109.3/resources/sap-ui-core.js"`

Comment: @PeDeGa what type of model are you using in your view? How do you bind the Planning Calendar to your model?

Comment: Having the same issue. CDS Entity model is: X-(1:N)-Y-(1:1)-Z. On DB level however association between Y and Z is 1:N due to multiple languages. So every query must explicitly use a filter on the current user-language to achieve the required 1:1 multiplicity. When creating a new association entry between X and Y I see the implicit refresh query happening without filter as well (after a page reload the query is using a filter and the page loads fine).

PS: Using UI5 1.108.10